# Does googlebot crawl the variable name of a php

Tags: php, googlebot, web-crawlers

Does Googlebot crawl the dynamic variable name aside from its value? For example in my PHP I use the variable `_company_name`. In the front-end is is `_company_name` saved in bot crawl also?

Comment: By "variable name" do you mean "URL parameter name" (ie. in the query string part of the URL)?

Comment: i not the url parameter but the content of the site upon loading

Answer (score 8):

Except in the case of misconfiguration, the PHP code is executed on the server and what gets transmitted to the client is only the result of the execution which may be a mix of static HTML + dynamic parts generated by PHP code.
That is the same no matter who the HTTP client is; a real browser used by a human, or an indexing robot.

Said differently, when your site is being indexed, your PHP source code is not seen at all, so you are free in this regard to do in it whatever you want, naming-wise or otherwise.

Comment: Except, of course, if you cause a notice / warning / traceback to appear on your frontend by not disabling error display :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Which is why I started with "Except misconfiguration".  Code spilling backtraces to the web browser is indeed a misconfiguration, first because the client can not do anything with that information, second because it can lead to a security vulnerability by exposing internal details. And you shouldn't disable errors by using `@` or equivalent in PHP, you should deal with them properly, but on server side only.

Comment: It's also simple to configure PHP so that error/warning messages are only logged on the server, not sent to the client.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek True, missed that

Comment: @PatrickMevzek For open source / free software, the tradeoff can be different; the source code is public anyway, and a backtrace could help somebody else fix the problem for you. (If it's a vulnerability rather than just a bug, and the user is malicious, it could help them a bit in crafting an attack, but unless you're doing regular audits yourself I don't see that hiding the backtrace would be safer.)

Comment: "and a backtrace could help somebody else fix the problem for you." Only in dev, certainly not in production. The backtrace can contain VALUES of data, including passwords and such, and not just the code. "I don't see that hiding the backtrace would be safer." This is not a problem of hiding the backtrace. Not giving it to client because 1) client can not do anything (even if he can see the problem and understand it, he can't go ssh/ftp on your server and fix the code/configuration anyway) 2) it is more frustrating/gibberish than anything else. Error should be dealt on server side.